# What are some reasons iOS crash reports are not logged?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an app made using react-native on Testflight with a small beta group. It's set to production mode.

One of my users is occasionally experiencing a fatal crash, which is not getting logged in the organiser > crashes. Other crashes in the past showed up there.

He has:

- Settings > Privacy > Analytics > Share iPhone Analytics = enabled
- Settings > Privacy > Analytics > Share with App Developers = enabled

What might be some other reasons this fatal error is not showing in my organiser?

My current theory is I am using too much CPU, which is triggering the device OS scheduler to crash the app and not allow resources to make the error report. When I profile the app I can have periods of 100%+ CPU usage for accounts with alot of data.

PS: I also have react-native-sentry installed which is not getting any error reports related to this either.

Comment: It is unknown how Apple filters the crashes it shows in Xcode compared to what it collects. In my experience it can take 24hours for data to appear. Ask the user to check the crash report on the device and sent it to you. Settings > Security & Privacy > Analytics > Analytic Data > Find the item in the list and use the share action

Comment: Interestingly enough, this user doesn't have any logs from my App in there apart from this:

`Event:           cpu usage
CPU:             144s cpu time over 152 seconds (95% cpu average), exceeding limit of 80% cpu over 180 seconds
Action taken:    none`

Comment: @RossKinsella Have you got any updates on this? One of my apps also crashing and giving such logs about high CPU usage. Some directions might be helpful.

Comment: Yes @Mrunal, it turned out I was spinning up far too many notification channels on app launch